# Is referring to 2 different xml files in a java code possible?

Tags: java, android, xml, popup, popupwindow

I have some problems with popup window. In the activity_main.xml i have a button to open a popup window in the middle of the screen.When i click on it popup window opens.I have created a custom layout (pop_up.xml, PopUp.java) for the popup window.In that layout, there is a button to close it.At the beginning, i had 2 different java files for these two xml files. In the MainActivity.java file, the 1st button behaves as i expected.But when i click on the button in the popup window it isn't triggered.So i tried to write that buttons code in the MainActivity.But now it gives me the error below:

```
Process: com.example.android.customcounter, PID: 30350
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.customcounter/com.example.android.customcounter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2439)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2499)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.ViewGroup.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference
at com.example.android.customcounter.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:68)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6556)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2499) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:166) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1360) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.android.customcounter;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    PopupWindow popupWindow;

    View layout_MainMenu;

    int number = 0;

    View popupView;

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    @TargetApi(23)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout_MainMenu = (View) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        //Foreground'daki siyah fonu saydam yapar
        layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha(0);

        Button eksi = (Button) findViewById(R.id.eksi);
        eksi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                number = number - 1;
                display(number);
            }
        });

        Button artı = (Button) findViewById(R.id.artı);
        artı.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                number = number + 1;
                display(number);
            }
        });

        Button seçenekler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seçenekler);
        seçenekler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
                popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, 900, 550, true);
                popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popupWindow.setAnimationStyle(android.R.style.Animation_Dialog);
                popupWindow.showAtLocation(popupView, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha(180);


            }

        });

        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
        Button kaydet = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.ayrintilar_kaydet);
        kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(layout_MainMenu);
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha(0);
            }
        });


    }


    private void display(int number) {

        TextView sayı = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.number_text_view);
        sayı.setText("" + number);
    }


}
```

Comment: `View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);` and then `Button kaydet = (Button)popupView .findViewById(R.id.ayrintilar_kaydet);` The views belong to the inflated layout

Comment: it gave me this error:

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.customcounter/com.example.android.customcounter.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference

Comment: Use debugger and start debugging. Its NullPointerException.

Comment: I put a breakpoint to the button casting code line.when it executes that code it says popupView=null and the app crashes.what am i supposed to do?

Comment: do you have the two lines i mentioned in the first comment inside one block. I mean together `View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);` and immediately `Button kaydet = (Button)popupView .findViewById(R.id.ayrintilar_kaydet);`. Can you post the revised code

Comment: ı changed the popupView as a global variable.its declaration is inside the first buttons code.Is that the problem?

Comment: Make sure you have those 2 lines inside onClick. if your variable is not initialized it will be null. May be you have a local variable initialized while your instance variable is not. Check that

Comment: how am i supposed to have those 2 lines inside onClick method?

Comment: View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
        Button kaydet = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.ayrintilar_kaydet);
        kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(layout_MainMenu);
                popupWindow.dismiss();
                layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha(0);
            }
        });

Comment: is this wrong then?

Comment: what happens now?

Comment: the app crashes. nothing different.

Comment: Its better you post your new code instead of comment by editing your post. Its NPE which should fairly easily to fix with a debugger

Comment: i posted the new code by editing it.

Comment: You are not supposed to remove the question details as it may be useful to people visiting this post later. Pls make sure you retain your question with relevant details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 ....
 View popupView; // this is a instance variable
```

Then you have

```
 Button seçenekler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seçenekler);
    seçenekler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // view infalted
            popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
```

So you need to use the popupView to find views in the hierarchy

```
      Button seçenekler = (Button) findViewById(R.id.seçenekler);
      seçenekler.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // view infalted
            popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up, null);
           Button kaydet = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.ayrintilar_kaydet);
           .... // rest of the code for button listener
           kaydet.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(layout_MainMenu);
            popupWindow.dismiss();
            layout_MainMenu.getForeground().setAlpha(0);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me.the app works now.the solution looks really simple.so i'm really sorry for bothering you for this long.i'm new to android development.Thanks again.